# Sub-string splitting - PHP

Tags: php, substring

So, I guess that this is a pretty simple concept, but I am unsure as to how I would achieve my intended result. What I am wanting, is for words which start with the '@' symbol, to be outputted with a `<span>` encasing them.

Let's say that the following is the whole string:

> Mark wants the new app to be released on Friday, but some assets need refining so that they fit the theme @design_team.

How would I capture the...

> @design_team

...sub-string, bearing in mind that characters other than an underscore should not be accounted for in the sub-string, to help keep the format.

Please let me know if this is possible with PHP, and if so, how.

Comment: You need to use regular expression and write your pattern to match any workd prepended by `@`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `preg_replace`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/@\w+/', '<span>$0</span>', $string);
```

`\w` matches word characters (letters, numbers, underscore), `+` makes it match a sequence of them. And in the replacement string `$0` gets the matching substring.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$str = "Mark wants the new app to be released on Friday, but some assets need refining so that they fit the theme @design_team.";
preg_match('/\@[a-zA-Z_]+/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => @design_team
)
```

Comment: I understand that this would print out the @design_team sub-string, but how would I print it as part of the string itself so that it was in the format of:

    <p>Mark wants... fit the theme <span>@design_team</span>.</p>

Comment: Never mind, Barmar has answered with this solution. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to achieve this. Here's an example:

```
$string = 'Hello @php and @regex!';

$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/@(\w+)/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(4) "@php"
    [1] =>
    string(6) "@regex"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "php"
    [1] =>
    string(5) "regex"
  }
}
```

Further reading: [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to use a regular expression *if you have multiple @words per string*:

```
$string = '@Mark wants the new app to be released @Friday, but it needs some @refining';
$didMatch = preg_match_all('/(@[^\W]+)/', $string, $matches);

if($didMatch) { 
    echo "There were " . count($matches[0]) . " matches: <br />";
    print_r($matches[0]);
} else { 
    echo "No @words in string!\n";
}
```